# IIS - Request filtering - failed request tracing not showing blocked file exentension

Tags: iis, iis-10

I have enabled the Failed Request Tracing in IIS 10. If I'm disabling the ***allow unlisted file name extensions*** within the ***request filtering***, then the failed request logs are generated. I can only see the 404 status, but there is no information about the blocked extension.

```
ModuleName: RequestFilteringModule 
Notification: BEGIN_REQUEST
HttpStatus: 404 
HttpReason: Not Found 
HttpSubStatus: 7 
ErrorCode: (0x0)
```

How can I get information which file extension has been blocked (to allow this extension)?

Comment: Isn't the URL enough?

Comment: I'm just getting **https://example.com/account/login** and no more information about the blocked extension.

Comment: I have created the list of used extensions as discussed their [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64370587/iis-list-of-common-file-extensions-request-filtering?noredirect=1#comment113849225_64370587) but the website is offline and I can't find any logs showing which exentsion is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. When that's the URL, the extension being blocked is simply `.`. You have to explicitly allow `.` or it will be blocked. I blogged about it a decade ago, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/lexli/iis-7-dot-tricks-part-ii

Comment: thank you, this resolved it